# How to get the floor of the current time to an hour in postman

Tags: postman

I am a new postman. I want to set a variable with the floor of the current time.
Example: current time is "2022-09-07T05:17:59" (UTC time) BUT I want to set a variable with the value "2022-09-07T00:00:00" (UTC time)
Does anyone help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean to the current hour, e.g. `"2022-09-07T05:00:00"` or the current day (as in your example), e.g. `"2022-09-07T00:00:00"`?

Comment: I mean I want to get the time at 05:00:00 while the current time is 05:17:59. If current time  is 06:30:17, expectation return result is 06:00:00

Comment: silly solution: replace 7 last characters of current time (in String) with `0:00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very elegant solution but should work

```
var floor_timestamp = new Date()
floor_timestamp.setMinutes(0)
floor_timestamp.setSeconds(0)
floor_timestamp.setMilliseconds(0)
console.log(floor_timestamp.toISOString())

pm.globals.set("timestamp", floor_timestamp)
```